# Mezzanine admin menu custom link

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I want to add in drop down menu an item link to export all records in CSV this is the code of admin:

```
class EntrantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('__unicode__', 'email' , 'date_of_birth', 'postcode')
readonly_fields = ('date_of_birth', 'answer')
search_fields = ['email','first_name', 'last_name']

def get_urls(self):
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^export/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.export),
            name='competition_entrant_export'),
    )
    urlpatterns += super(EntrantAdmin, self).get_urls()
    return urlpatterns

def export(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Get all the field names from the Entrant model so we can export them
    # in our csv file. We don't want the database primary key, though.
    fields = map(attrgetter('name'), Entrant._meta.fields)
    fields.remove('id')

    # Construct a File-like object, in this case a Response, to write
    # our csv data to. Also specify that it should be treated as an
    # attachment (if not in debug mode).
    stream = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    if not settings.DEBUG:
        filename = 'competition.csv'
        stream['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename

    writer = csv.DictWriter(stream, fields, dialect=quoteall)
    try:
        writer.writeheader()
    except AttributeError:  # Python < 2.7
        writer.writerow(dict(zip(fields,fields)))
    writer.writerows(Entrant.objects.values(*fields))

    return stream
admin.site.register(Entrant, EntrantAdmin)
```

and functionality works if you enter url manualy "/admin/competition/entrant/export"

How to add new menu item in dropdwon menu link with url: /admin/competition/entrant/export

to looks like

[image: I want that red menu item]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question you can add a [custom item](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/admin-customization.html#custom-items) to the menu that has your url as a named url there.

```
ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
    ("Content", ("pages.Page", "blog.BlogPost", "blog.Comment",
        ("Export Entrants", "competition_entrant_export"),)),
    ("Site", ("auth.User", "auth.Group", "sites.Site", "redirects.Redirect")),
)
```

Another easy way is to use a django [admin action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/). This will be a tiny bit of a hack since you need to select at least one item to ensure the action triggers properly. But if this is a staff admin it would be easy to educate them how to use it. In the action you would just ignore the queryset parameter.